# Mail Retrieve Software for Microsoft 365

Tags: imap, fetchmail, getmail

As Microsoft 365 is moving to Oauth2, and Fetchmail didn't release a stable version supporting it (only an Alpha on the version 7, but not solid), my organization is looking for a IMAP mail retrieve service like Fetchmail to:

Save on the disk mail data like:

```
header
body
attachments
```

This service/daemon should run on a linux server.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use Getmail, I can't find a configuration for Microsoft 365, only for Gmail.

** UPDATE **

I've found an application called Mutt, and I'm following this documentation:

[mutt oauth2](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/master/contrib/mutt_oauth2.py.README)

But I get no authenticators available for now, I bet I'll miss something in the muttrc config, or in the Azure configurations.

My plans is to use this library, also:

[mutt wizard](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/mutt-wizard)

expecially for the isync integration. I don't have experience with MailDir, but probably when I have the backups into my disk it would be easier to get mail info + attachements.

Anyone that have experience with this?

** 2 UPDATE **

I opened an issue on Mutt Github. I can't find a way to save Outlook Mail locally.

Comment: What have your tried and/or searched/researched so far?

Comment: I've tried to use mutt, I'm following this https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/master/contrib/mutt_oauth2.py.README